# How do I setup my voip phone to use VPN server?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, voip

I've installed Bria 4 on Windows 7 pc. I've got a 15MbPS broadband connection. The Bria on my PC fail to register with this network. However if I connect to VPN server(hide.me), with the broadband connection I'm able to get the Bria Working.

Now I want to get my VOIP hardphone working. Given that Bria works successfully with a VPN server what options I've to get my VOIP hardphone working?

I know I can always buy a VPN enabled router but it does cost me few bucks.

Is there a way I can use my computer(with Windows 7) as a VPN router/server(may be with additional ethernet card)?

I just need to make my VOIP Phone use VPN service.

Comment: You realize the PC would have to be running all the time, right? Unless it’s very energy-efficient, spending $30-40 to get a mini router is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your computer into a router, but the routing issues become complex - particularly if you are used to a simple home-user environment where the router provides DHCP and routing.  In order to further assist here we would need to know a lot more details about your network (how your router connects to your PC, how many interfaces your PC has, including Wifi and wireless, what else is on your network.

In general terms you would need to:

```
1.  Set up a secondary interface (possibly a virtual Interface) on your
    PC in a different subnet.
2.  [Configure your PC to act as a router][1]
3.  C[onfigure your PC to perform NAT (ICS/Internet Connection Sharing).][1]
4.  Configure your phone with a static IP address which points to your
    computer as a default gateway (and is in the same IP range as the
    secondary interface on your PC.
```

Have you ascertained that your ISP is not blocking VOIP traffic, and have you looked at the configuration on the router (what kind of router is it ?  Does it support a DMZ or can you otherwise port-forwarding, are you sure you can't flash your router with dd-wrt or similar ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of VoIP phones out there that have built-in VPN support. Be sure to check your settings for the VPN setup information.

Our favorite brand, Yealink, uses OpenVPN to provide IP Sec support. http://www.yealink.com/Upload/T2X/20131125/OpenVPN_Feature_on_Yealink_IP_Phones.pdf. Other popular brands such as Cisco and Polycom also have built-in VPN support.